# How to filter item based on id and subId?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

Hey I am making a food delivery app, and I have a list of data. I want to remove the item if the condition matches:

- If the **id**  and **subDataId** matches, remove that item.
- If only the **id** matches (and I don't have **subDataId** I can use for a comparison) then remove that item.

Here is my data

```
state: [
    {
      id: 1,
      quantity: 4,
      price: 120,
      subDataId: 1,
      itemTotalPrice: 480
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      quantity: 5,
      price: 70,
      subDataId: 2,
      itemTotalPrice: 350
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      quantity: 3,
      price: 140,
      subDataId: 1,
      itemTotalPrice: 420
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      quantity: 5,
      price: 80,
      subDataId: 2,
      itemTotalPrice: 400
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      quantity: 6,
      price: 60,
      itemTotalPrice: 360
    }
  ],
```

Here is my code

```
let data = {id: 1, subDataId: 2};
// let data ={id: 3}

if (data.subDataId) {
        const filtered = state.filter((filterItem) => {
           return (
            filterItem.id !== data.id && filterItem.subDataId !== data.subDataId
           );        });
        if (filtered.length !== 0) {
          return (state = filtered);
        } else {
          return [...state];
        }
} else {
      const filtered = state.filter((filterItem) => {
          return filterItem.id !== data.id;
      });
      if (filtered.length !== 0) {
          return (state = filtered);
      } else {
          return [...state];
        }
      }
```

The code does not work properly and remove several items instead of one.

**EDIT** Guys, Guys I want to check if the **id** and **subdDataId** matches then remove the item and return an array with the rest of the data and if only the **id**matches then do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filterItem.id !== data.id && filterItem.subDataId !== data.subDataId` is not correct. You want to remove the item if the id and subDataId matches, i.e. `filterItem.id === data.id && filterItem.subDataId === data.subDataId`. Therefore, you want to keep the item if `!(filterItem.id === data.id && filterItem.subDataId === data.subDataId)`

```js
const state = [
    {
      id: 1,
      quantity: 4,
      price: 120,
      subDataId: 1,
      itemTotalPrice: 480
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      quantity: 5,
      price: 70,
      subDataId: 2,
      itemTotalPrice: 350
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      quantity: 3,
      price: 140,
      subDataId: 1,
      itemTotalPrice: 420
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      quantity: 5,
      price: 80,
      subDataId: 2,
      itemTotalPrice: 400
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      quantity: 6,
      price: 60,
      itemTotalPrice: 360
    }
  ];

function filter(data) {
if (data.subDataId) {
    const filtered = state.filter((filterItem) => 
            !(filterItem.id === data.id && filterItem.subDataId === data.subDataId));
        if (filtered.length !== 0) {
          return filtered;
        } else {
          return [...state];
        }
} else {
      const filtered = state.filter((filterItem) => {
          return filterItem.id !== data.id;
      });
      if (filtered.length !== 0) {
          return filtered;
      } else {
          return [...state];
      }
}

}
console.log(filter({id:1, subDataId:2}));
console.log(filter({id:1}));
```

Comment: I'm confused. How are you getting three items as result. If condition 1 is `true` condition 2 is automatically `true` as well.

Comment: @Behemoth, sorry, you are confusing me, too ;-) Which one is condition 1, and which is condition 2?

Comment: I'm talking about the ones provided in the initial question.

Comment: @Behemoth You are right about the conditions.

Comment: @Behemoth if you look at the provided implementation, the second condition should really read: If only the id matches (and I don't have subDataId I can use for a comparison) then remove that item. (I based my answer on that implementation)

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
let newState = state.filter((item) =>{
   return item.id !== data.id && item.subDataId !== data.subDataId; 
});
```

Comment: please add some explanation to your answer [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are overthinking the problem a little bit. Why not use a simple [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)? In your explanation condition 2 is `true` as soon as condition 1 is `true`. So the actual condition is:

- item `id` && `subDataId` must match the values to be removed.

Try this:

```js
const data = [{
    id: 1,
    quantity: 4,
    price: 120,
    subDataId: 1,
    itemTotalPrice: 480,
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    quantity: 5,
    price: 70,
    subDataId: 2,
    itemTotalPrice: 350,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    quantity: 3,
    price: 140,
    subDataId: 1,
    itemTotalPrice: 420,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    quantity: 5,
    price: 80,
    subDataId: 2,
    itemTotalPrice: 400,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    quantity: 6,
    price: 60,
    itemTotalPrice: 360,
  },
];

const result = data.filter((item) => item.id !== 1 && item.subDataId !== 2);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This answers is very specific to few values, code should be dynamic and for all possible values.

Comment: @SajidRSK Should it? There's absolutely nothing said about that in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with from your description. You can run the snippet to check the result.

To filter items with `subDataId` you have to use `||` instead of `&&`.

```js
const state = [
  {
    id: 1,
    quantity: 4,
    price: 120,
    subDataId: 1,
    itemTotalPrice: 480,
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    quantity: 5,
    price: 70,
    subDataId: 2,
    itemTotalPrice: 350,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    quantity: 3,
    price: 140,
    subDataId: 1,
    itemTotalPrice: 420,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    quantity: 5,
    price: 80,
    subDataId: 2,
    itemTotalPrice: 400,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    quantity: 6,
    price: 60,
    itemTotalPrice: 360,
  },
];

function filterItem(data, itemToRemove) {
  let filteredData = [...data];
  // we are checking if itemToRemove has subDataId
  if (itemToRemove.subDataId) {
    // we are only taking an item if it's id or subDataId doesn't match with itemToRemove's id or subDataId
    filteredData = data.filter(
      (item) =>
        item.id !== itemToRemove.id || item.subDataId !== itemToRemove.subDataId
    );
  } else {
    // if itemToRemove doesn't have subDataId we are only taking an item if it's id doesn't match with itemToRemove's id
    filteredData = data.filter((item) => item.id !== itemToRemove.id);
  }

  return filteredData;
}

const item1 = { id: 1};
const item2 = { id: 1, subDataId: 1 };

console.log('Without subDataId', filterItem(state, item1));
console.log('With subDataId', filterItem(state, item2));
```

Answer (score 0):

It will check if id and subDataId matches with data or just id matches with data.

```
const filteredArary = state.filter(item => !((item.id === data.id && item.subDataIdd === data.subDataId) || item.id === data.id))
```